# jquery flot x-axis labeling location

Tags: jquery, charts, flot

please refer to http://jsfiddle.net/UEePE/1029/

How can I put the x-axis to the top of the chart instead at the bottom of the chart?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `position` to `top`.

```
var data = [[-373597200000, 315.71], [-370918800000, 317.45], [-368326800000, 317.50],  [-99968400000, 319.79]]; 

$.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
        yaxis: {
        },
        xaxis: { mode: "time",
                 ticks: 18,
                 minTickSize: [1, "month"], 
                 tickLength: 1,
                 min: (new Date("2000/01/01")).getTime(),
                 max: (new Date("2001/07/02")).getTime(),
                 position: "top" //<<-------------- will set X axis to top
},
        "lines": {"show": "true"},
        "points": {"show": "true"},
        clickable:true,hoverable: true
});
```

Working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UEePE/1032/)**

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jsGLP/

Answer (score 1):

```
  xaxis: { postion:"top",...
```

see : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/7FfMd/2/